# TypeScript index signatures class implementation

Tags: typescript

consider following code snippet:

```
export interface IProduct {
    [key: string]: number | boolean;
}

export class Product implements IProduct {
    b: number;
    c: boolean;
}
```

I'd expect TypeScript to understand this like follow:

> Hey, the `IProduct` interface can be any sort of object with any
>   number of fields which can by one of following types: 
>   `number` or `boolean`. Now the class that implements this interface
>   basically can contains exactly same fields variation

Unfortunately, above code gives me error, that class does not implement interface correctly, forcing me to re-type index type into class itself:

```
export class Product implements IProduct {
    [key: string]:  number | boolean;
    b: number;
    c: boolean;
}
```

But to be honest my expectations were that I can just declare class fields and as long as they conform to interface declaration contract I'll get no error like below:

```
export class Product implements IProduct {
    b: number;
    c: boolean;
    a: string /* Gives erorr, since string is not allowed index type */
}
```

Any ideas on how to bypass this or just my understanding is simply wrong?

Answer (score 6):

You can create a type that enforces the constraint you want but it will have to be a mapped type:

```
export type IProduct<T> = Record<keyof T, number | boolean>
// Or, same effect but using the actual mapped type
// export type IProduct<T> = {
//    [P in keyof T]: number | boolean;
//}

export class Product implements IProduct<Product> {
    b: number;
    c: boolean;
}
```

The reason typescript complains is that the interface index signature would allow you to index with any string, but the class only has specific keys. If your class can in deed have any keys then it should have the index signature to make this explicit.

**Edit**

Different version, where the generic type parameter of the interface are the keys the interface will have:

```
export type IProduct<T extends PropertyKey> = Record<T, number | boolean>

export class Product implements IProduct<keyof Product> {
    b: number;
    c: boolean;
}
let o: IProduct<'c' | 'b'> = new Product();
```

Comment: I would't expect any ones else answer except yours Titan :)

Comment: @Tomas :)) I spend way to much time around here :)